# Merge 2 data streams into 1 after using pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, pandas

I have two separate curl calls, which generate two separate csv files. Both files have a common field(name_id). I am trying to merge these files and print them on console.

1. From first csv, I want to add all columns in table(name_id, phone_num, zip). There will be two more columns(cases_week1, cases_week2) which are not part of first csv but they are in second csv.
2. From second csv, I want to add all values of (cases_week1 and cases_week2) where there is match between both files using common column(name_id)If there is no match, simply move over to next record.

P.S: First csv will always have more rows than second csv.

```
cd_curl csv
----------------
name_id, phone_num, zip
abc123, 9989898, 12345
def456, 3874982, 45678
ghi789, 7728261, 91011

cc_curl csv
-----------------
name_id, cases_week1, cases_week2
abc123, 3, 3
def456, 5, 2
zzz111, 7, 11

Table structure
---------------
CREATE TABLE `data`.`call` (
  `name_id` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  `phone_num` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `zip` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `cases_week1` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `cases_week2` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`name_id`)
)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

Code
----
#!/usr/bin/python3

import pandas as pd

cd_curl = "url-1-hidden-due-to-security"    
cc_curl = "url-2-hidden-due-to-security"

cd= pd.read_csv(cd_curl)
cc= pd.read_csv(cc_curl)

for row in cd.to_dict(orient="records"):
    print(row['name_id'], row['phone_num'], row['zip'])


Desired output
--------------
abc123 9989898 12345 3 3
def456 3874982 45678 5 2
ghi789 7728261 91011
```

How can I print the values of cases_week1 and cases_2 where the name_id matches?

Comment: Have you looked at the `zip` and `filter` [builtins](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html)?

Comment: @Gator_Python. I have not. Being a new programmer and thrown in the pool, I do not know a lot.

Comment: Don't use `zip` or `filter`.  Just use Pandas' [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html). See the Pandas [documentaion](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#database-style-dataframe-joining-merging) on `merge`, or the SO [documentation](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/pandas/1966/merge-join-and-concatenate/6717/merging-two-dataframes#t=201610171912263063848) on `merge`.

Comment: @root. Thank you for guidance. Following did the job for me.

`cd.merge(cc, how='left')`